# QuickGame in google play games multiplayer - necessarily inside my google circle?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer

Does the [quickgame](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#quick_game_option) option, in the multiplayer google play games, match random players who are in (i) one's google plus circle or (ii) any online player.

I want to implement quickgame with anyone who is online, and I could not find anything in documentation or elsewhere that clarifies if a "random player" can be outside my circle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realtime Quick game option selects from random players according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#quick_game_option).

> **Quick Game option** - When the player selects the Quick Game option, your
>   game should create a virtual room object to join players, auto-match
>   the player to randomly selected opponents without displaying the
>   player picker UI, and immediately start the game.

We can safely assume that it selects “Any online player”. You can also make specific criterias during selection by using the `exclusiveBitMask`
parameter of the `createAutoMatchCriteria` function